# What are the resricted tithis for a women to take oil bath?

Tags: scripture, women, oil

What are the restricted tithis for a women to take oil bath? Are there any scriptural references? If so, can you please provide them  with some scriptural references?

The verses has to be explicitly dedicated to women as most of the verses are generally intended for men.